# Mongoose require a field based on some enum values of another field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose schema `Employee`. In that I want to store a field (phone number) related to office  for the employee, only if he/she is eligible for office, which is only for two levels "senior" and "c-level".

The schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    designation: String,
    level: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["intern", "junior", "mid-level", "senior", "c-level"],
        required: true,
    },
    phoneNo: { type: String, required: true },
    officePhoneNo: { type: String, required: true } // How to require only if the level is senior or c-level?,
});
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: You want a "custom validator". More advanced validation is discussed in the [mongoose manual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, I'll go through the manual :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Mongoose you can pass a function in `required` that can return `true/false` depending on some condition.

It's also possible to depend `required` of a field on other fields, which is `level` in your case. That is, you can optionally required a field.  Here's how:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const levels = ["intern", "junior", "mid-level", "senior", "c-level"];
const levelsEligibleForOffice = ["senior", "c-level"];

var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    designation: String,
    level: {type: String, enum: levels, required: true},
    phoneNo: {type: String, required: true},
    officePhoneNo: {type: String, required: isEligibleForOffice}
});


function isEligibleForOffice(){
    if(levelsEligibleForOffice.indexOf(this.level) > -1){  //"this" contains the employee document at the time of required validation
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```